# IPB: equivalent for $this->registry->class_forums->forum_by_id

Tags: ipb

Hi,

I would like to know whats the right code that does the same as

```
$this->registry->class_forums->forum_by_id[ $forumid ];
```

but for posts?

I thought it was something like:

```
$this->registry->classPost->post_by_topic_id[ $topic_id ];
```

but it wont work. Could you please give me a hint?

Thank you.

Comment: Hey! What about some help?? HEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEELPPPPPPPP!!!!